# c#: ExcelDNA custom rubbon with list

Tags: list, button, excel-dna

i'm trying to add a custom rubbon for excel, i can easily add a button, but can't add a list; it means a button, when you clic on it, it display a list of items like this :

[image]

here is my code but don't work, an idea ?

```
<group id='myVersion2' label='About' visible='true'>
          <RibbonButton.ToolTip>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
              <TextBlock FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Header" />
              <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="Content .... " />
            </StackPanel>
          </RibbonButton.ToolTip>
        </group>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Ribbon follows the [Custom UI XML Markup Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313070(v=office.12).aspx) and
>   supports a defined set of elements, as you can see in the
>   [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/ribbon-xml).

It seems your are confusing the fact that it's an XML spec and trying to declare WPF elements in there, which are obviously not supported.

You can see examples of Custom UI Ribbons in the Excel-DNA repository:
https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/tree/master/Distribution/Samples/Ribbon

Comment: i tryed the "commandbars" described in the github example but my add-in want load anymore (i click on activate the plugin but nothing happens)